# Firebase Cloud Messaging authorization failure

Tags: go, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently trying to implement a server in Go working with Firebase Cloud Messaging. I inserted my API key and sender ID (which I both got from the Firebase console at Project Settings -> Cloud Messaging) and did this:

```
err := gcm.Listen(senderID, apiKey, onMessageReceived, nil)
```

and all I get is this

> error creating xmpp client>error connecting client>auth failure: not-authorized

I'm using the same [library](https://github.com/google/go-gcm) Google's using in it's [examples](https://github.com/googlesamples/gcm-playground/blob/master/server/server.go). Is the library maybe not working with FCM yet or am I doing something wrong?

If it's the library, how would I implement this without it?

Comment: Hi mkocs, I am not able to reproduce this issue. (I tried creating a new project and the library you linked works for me.)
Could you please reach out to support and report your sender-id and your api-key ?
https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/ thanks!

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini I already sent a message to support a few hours ago, but without the API key and sender id. Should I just send another?

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini Could you maybe create a gist with the code of the project you created and send me a link? I'd really appreciate it. Maybe I just made a mistake working with the library.

Comment: I will follow up there! thanks

Answer (score 1):

This library will works perfectly with firebase, if you do several things:

1. Change xmppHost from https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
2. Add new const xmppDomain = "gcm.googleapis.com"
3. Change function **xmppUser**, it should be like

```go
func xmppUser(senderId string) string {
    return senderId + "@" + xmppDomain
}
```

Comment: the correct value to xmppHost is fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com. The rest of the solution is correct.